# Access 2007: Conditional Formatting not working for control based on lookup value

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2007 report with a control based on a lookup field which has a list of values.  The field values are strings:

```
0. Late
1. Critical
2. Urgent
3. Normal
4. Low
5. Closed
6. Draft/On Hold
```

In the conditional formatting box, I use:

```
Field Value Is equal to "0) Late"
```

and choose a different color background and text color.  This should conditionally change the background and text color of the textbox when it's value matches "0) Late", however instead of showing up as expected, the report simply doesn't print that value.

Access help says "When you apply conditional formatting to a lookup field, the condition must be based on the lookup ID, not the value returned by the lookup field."

I'm not sure what it means by `Lookup ID`.  Is that a number based on the position in the lookup value list?  I've tried using `1` instead of `0) Late`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: This questions seems more suited to superuser. Do you mean you have included look-up fields in your table? Unless you are using sharepoint, these can only cause you problems such as this.

Answer (score 0):

The fields in the report were set with background "Transparent"; the backgrounds needed to be set to "Normal" for the fill colors to show up.